# Angular 6.x independent component styles bundle

Tags: angular, angular6

Is it possible to generate CSS bundle file for my angular 6.x App components styles. I tried `extractCss` true which actually generated inline `<style>` in my index.html but I would like to rather have an independent `components.css`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Only global css can be bundled separetely. Angular core members vision is to always include components style to the bundle (this is by design they said). See this issue https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7219